# PowerShell Write-Host not synchronous

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script to check some properties of a server. When I execute the following cmdlets **in order**, the output is not displayed in the order I expect.

```
Write-Host "=== Operating System ==="
Get-WmiObject -computername $ServerName -class Win32_OperatingSystem | select Caption | ft -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize

Write-Host "=== Pagefile ==="
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ServerName -Class Win32_PageFileSetting

Write-Host "=== Locale ==="
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ServerName -class Win32_OperatingSystem | select Locale | ft -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize | Write-Output
```

**Output:**

> === Operating System ===
>
> Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Standard
>
> === Pagefile ===
>
> === Locale ===
>
> MaximumSize Name            Caption
>   ----------- ----            -------
>          4000 C:\pagefile.sys C:\ 'pagefile.sys'
>
> 0813

How does it come that the pagefile output is not displayed under its title? It seems to me that `Get-WmiObject` is running asynchronously and immediately writes the next title (Locale).

How can I prevent this? It works when using Write-Output, but then I cannot use colored text.

Comment: Try piping the second `Get-WmiObject` call to `|ft` explicitly like you do with the others - also, don't pipe formatted output to write-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your text on-screen comes from objects going through the [PowerShell pipeline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/back-to-the-basics-part-1-learn-about-the-powershell-pipeline/), and some comes from `Write-Host` which prints to the screen immediately without touching the pipeline.

Gathering WMI information about the pagefile takes time and outputs to the pipeline, but the script has already moved on to printing the Locale message before that pipeline has finished.

This doesn't happen for (Operating System), because that pipeline finishes with `ft -AutoSize` (Format-Table), which pauses the script and waits for everything in the pipeline so it has as much information as possible when deciding how to size the columns. Once `ft` prints to the screen, then the script moves to the PageFile message.

You should use `Write-Output` instead to send the text through the pipeline, this way it will integrate well with other PowerShell features like redirection, collecting command output in files and variables.

Jeffrey Snover (PowerShell lead architect) has written about why `Write-Host` is not recommended on his blog here: http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/

Here's a link describing the behaviour of `Format-Table`:

> Optimizing Column Width
>
> Because the pipeline processes results in real time, PowerShell cannot know how wide of a space the column elements will occupy. As a result, it will tend to be generous in sizing columns. If you specify the -AutoSize parameter, Format-Table will collect all results first before setting the maximum width for all elements. You can optimize output, but the results will no longer be output in real time:
>
> [Master-PowerShell | With Dr. Tobias Weltner](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/ebookv2/posts/chapter-5-the-powershell-pipeline#optimizing-column-width)

Comment: `Format-Table` indeed did the trick. Is there a way to use colors with `Write-Output` as well?

Comment: @EsTeGe Not really. That's like asking if you can use colours in a text text file or store coloured text in a variable. If you only want to show text on screen then `Write-Host` is the tool for the job - but if you want status messages from a script as it progresses, Write-Output is a better habit to get into, then the script output can be logged to a file to see what happened or stored in a variable and checked, and so on. You could use `Write-Warning` and `Write-Error` which show up in different colours - but they are separate channels intended for logging warnings and errors.

Comment: Sure, I understand that analogy, but maybe there could be a way that piping coloured text to a file would simply ignore the colour, but still show the colours on the screen. Think of it like printing a coloured text in black & white on paper. Anyway, I'm using `Write-Output` now.

Comment: @EsTeGe What colour is `$x="hello"` in memory? You could include colour information inside the text - write HTML `<p style='color:red'>hello</p>` and view in a web browser, for example. Or RichText and view in WordPad. Or ANSII colour codes and view in a third party Linux style terminal. The text is still colourless though; it always will be, and if you output it to a text file the display markup metadata won't be ignored because it's part of the text.